# How to send Mobile Email Using Exact Target SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have Mobile Email Template in Exact Target. Now my requirement is send that email template to mobile inbox through Exact Target using SOAP API.

I'm new to Exact Target.So I don't have any idea about how to use exact target.

Can any one help me how to implement this in SFDC and what are the Steps required to do this.

Thanks ,
Murali

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in regards to what part of DC you are using,  where you might use the API, what type of email send you are performing. Need more detail to answer this one.